# How to insert a new item to mLab array according to a specific id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mlab

I use mLab for my database. I have a collection of lists where each list has an object with _id, userId and an array of items.

Now I want to add a new item to the array of a specific list.

The function that connects to Mongo has the new item object and the list id.

How do I find the correct list and add the new item to items array?

the JSON of each list looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ded5eb7e7179a3015b0672f"
    },
    "userID": "1234",
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "abc12345",
            "name": "abc",
        },
        {
            "_id": "abc12346",
            "name": "def",
        }
    ]
}
```

and the function that connects to Mongo looks like this:

```js
function addItem({item, listId}) {
    return MongoService.connect()
    .then(db => {
        const collection = db.collection('lists');
        //need to do something here
    })
}
```

connect to Mongo : (which works fine, I do connect and load the lists)

```js
function connectToMongo() {
    if (dbConn) return Promise.resolve(dbConn);
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url = 'mongodb:// ***my user and password ***';
    return MongoClient.connect(url)
        .then(client => {
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
            client.on('close', ()=>{
                console.log('MongoDB Diconnected!');
                dbConn = null;
            })
            dbConn = client.db()
            return dbConn;
        })
}
module.exports = {
    connect : connectToMongo
}
```

Comment: Are you open to using a library to solve this problem?

Comment: What did you have in mind?

Comment: Ramda and/or partial.lenses

Comment: I am guessing `MongoService` is coming from an external module somewhere, is it a third party package? If yes, what package is it?

Comment: @OTZ I have another module with function conectToMongo. I use it to load the lists and it works fine

Comment: When dealing with MongoDB in javascript(node), I'd expect you to be using either mongoose or the MongoDB node driver, are you using any of these? If no, I would like to know how you connect and query MongoDB for the lists, that would help figure out how to go about doing a find query.

Comment: @OTZ I edit my question so it includes the Mongo connect function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using the MongoDB node native driver. Documentation exists on how to update a MongoDB document with the driver [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/).

In order to add an item to `list.items` array, this is what the `addItem` function should look like:

```
function addItem({ item, listId }) {
  return MongoService.connect()
    .then(db => {
      const collection = db.collection('lists');
      // The update query below would return a promise
      return collection.updateOne({
        { _id: new ObjectID(listId) }
      }, { '$push': { items: item } })
    })
    .then(result => { // Anything you want to do with the result })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! that was helpful but I needed to change the _id to :
 `{ "_id": new ObjectID(listId) }`  Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally reach for a library like [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) and/or [partial.lenses](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses) to solve a problem like this. Either of those libraries will simplify working with complicated and/or nested data that often comes from mongodb.

partial.lenses is probably the more powerful option for dealing with complicated, nested data structures, but I'm not sure how to embed it in a snippet here, and Ramda is no slouch in this area, so here's a Ramda example:

```js
const lists = [
  {
    _id: { $oid: '1234' },
    items: []
  },
  {
    _id: { $oid: '2345' },
    items: []
  },
  {
    _id: { $oid: '3456' },
    items: []
  }
]

function addItem({item, listId}) {
  const ix = lists.findIndex(
    ({ _id }) => _id.$oid === listId
  )
  return R.over(R.lensPath([ix, 'items']), R.append(item), lists)
}

console.log(
  addItem({ item: 'hi', listId: '1234' })
)

console.log(
  addItem({ item: 'hi', listId: '3456' })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

For posterity, here's a link to a [working solution based on partial.lenses](https://calmm-js.github.io/partial.lenses/playground.html#MYewdgzgLgBANiA5jAvDAHqgfDAFKSEOAUwDoFFd0BKAGg2oChGDp4BLaCVGAbUYDejAPrsAJgC4YAmABIQ4qQHIAjACYAzABYlMAL61G7KMQC2EKbwC6jA4JGLpchZJhLNWgKy67xsxb4bOyFRVxl5RyVtTwA2H0M-c0sgxhsWcDYAQwAHbOIwMR5E7BhMgCcyzIBPEt5SevLKqvpEtIAzAFcwYCh2cFKxMQBJE1NcAUT6OE4oIbE9aml0yFh2TDRprlI29gKhguJ0XEZxmFD9RZQcUNIIwpQHjmg5xiYy4igOsrAYABlSUwgMTsNpVXC8Nb0JSJCBKKz0HJ5Aq4RJ0J5QCBMPTMTKDEZmU6JZQAC3YSimMzmynU2h81CAA).

Here's a solution that has no library dependencies. Honestly, it's a bit messy, and if I were not able to use a library, I would spend some time writing a handful of reusable utility functions that would become a part of any actual production solution I wrote. I've done this on previous projects, but the code isn't open source, and I think that exercise is outside the scope of this answer.

I hope this working example will get you moving in the right direction:

```js
const _lists = [
  {
    _id: { $oid: '1234' },
    items: []
  },
  {
    _id: { $oid: '2345' },
    items: []
  },
  {
    _id: { $oid: '3456' },
    items: []
  }
]

const getListById = (listId, lists) =>
  lists.find(({ _id }) => _id.$oid === listId)

const setListById = (listId, newList, lists) =>
  lists.reduce(
    (acc, list, i) =>
      list._id.$oid === listId
        ? (acc.push(newList), acc)
        : (acc.push(list), acc),
    []
  )

function addItem({item, listId}) {
  const oList = getListById(listId, _lists)
  const newList = {
    ...oList,
    items: [...oList.items, item]
  }
  return setListById(listId, newList, _lists)
}

console.log(
  addItem({ item: 'hi', listId: '1234' })
)

console.log(
  addItem({ item: 'hi', listId: '3456' })
)
```

Also, a caveat: All of these examples assume there will always be a list object matching the provided `listId`. If that's not a safe assumption, you'll need to add some logic to handle the failure case (i.e. `findIndex` will return `-1` rather than an actual array index and `find` will returned `undefined` rather than a list object).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. But is there any direct solution without external library?